# Angular JS : Unordered List Elements not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to create a unordered list using controller and view page. Please find the controller below:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.sdb')
    .controller('SdbController', SdbController)

  SdbController.$inject = ['logger'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function SdbController(logger) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.models = {
      selected: null,
      lists: {"A": [], "B": []}
    };

    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
      vm.models.lists.A.push({label: "Item A" + i});
      vm.models.lists.B.push({label: "Item B" + i});

    }

    activate();

    function activate() {
      vm.title = 'Safe Digital Board';
      logger.info('Activation', 'Sdb Controller', 'Template Rendered');
    }
  }
})();
```

Please find the mark up below:

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in vm.models"> Hello {{item.label}} </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

But am getting only the below O/P:

- Hello
- Hello

Seeking help... Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your model object. Your ng-repeat should be `ng-repeat="item in vm.models.lists.A"`
Please find a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xdj9KTwdAcXPHbiIWhec?p=preview)

```
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in vm.models.lists.A"> Hello {{item.label}} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

To show both lists you need to write your template as shown below:

```
  <div>
    <ul ng-repeat="items in vm.models.lists">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items"> Hello {{item.label}} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Raja... I am novice really angular... But if i want to display my 'List B' what needs to be done

Comment: is your list B is separate <ul>  or under same one?

Comment: under same one only.. basically an trying to replicate the below setup [DragnDrop](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple)

Comment: Yes, the second block of HTML will fit for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try using $scope and create an array for $scope.vm.models, like:

```
.controller('SdbController', ['$scope', $log,
      function($scope, $log) {            
            $scope.reset = function() {
                $scope.vm = {};
                $scope.vm.models = [{label:"element01"},
            };
            $scope.reset();                           
      }                 
    }]);
```